# What are some faculty positions focused purely on research in Europe?

Tags: funding, job-search, job

In the UK we have fellowships at various levels depending on experience, in which there is no obligation to teach. What are other similar positions in Europe (including the UK)?

Comment: You do realize that the UK is part of Europe.

Comment: I think you need to provide a little more detail about the "level" (e.g., post doc, Lecturer, or Professor) and duration (e.g., fixed-term or permanent) and maybe even field.

Answer (score 2):

Surely, yes. For example, institutes of [Max Planck Society](http://www.mpg.de/en) in Germany are primarily research focused. They offer positions of various levels (postdocs, group leaders, professors) which can be 100% research (i.e. there is an opportunity but no duty to teach).

Comment: I think the MPIs are a little different from what the OP is asking about. From my understanding they are not degree granting institutions and would be more like the MRC institutes in the UK. I think the Marie Curie fellowships might be closer to what the OP is asking about.